# Is it possible to format VS Code property titles in package.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Suppose I have the following property defined in my `package.json`

```
"myextension.myApiVersion": {
    "type": "string",
    "default": "",
    "description": "The API version to use."
}
```

When I look at that setting in the Settings page of VS Code, it automatically gets formatted to "My Api Version". Is there a way to specify my own formatting so that it shows "My API Version"?

Comment: I don't think that's currently supported. The ability to have custom labels (among other things) was mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/70589#issuecomment-473562461